# [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Cursor type changed

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have query using sql server

```
WITH OrderedOrders AS ( SELECT a.ArticleID, a.Title, a.Summary, b.PageText, a.LastUpdate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a.ArticleID desc) AS 'RowNumber'
FROM DnnForge_NewsArticles_Article a
left join DnnForge_NewsArticles_Page b on b.ArticleID=a.ArticleID
where a.MOduleID=796
)
SELECT * FROM OrderedOrders WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

I try to test on Sql Server Management Studio running well, but when I test on php there is some error : `[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Cursor type changed`

Please help me